# On 12.10 & 13.04 with i915 Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, graphics, gpu, i915

My system has been stable for about 3 months then without warning I started to get a freeze of the display and then a problem report saying GPU hung.

I have update the graphics driver as per [How to install Intel 82852/855GM driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4658/how-to-install-intel-82852-855gm-driver/4802#4802) so I know that I have the latest driver available but I still keep getting, and reporting, regular GPU hang messages.  Now every now and then the screen freezes in a big way and I can only proceed by ssh in from a separate machine and killing off lightdm and then restarting it and logging in again.

If anyone has fixed this problem it would be good to know the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have a temp fix for this issue.  It was getting so bad that the system was almost of no use with a failure every few minutes and complete hang every hour or so.

Looking in /var/log/Xorg.0.log I found that the existing driver was using UXA:

> [ 12.905] (II) UXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
>   [ 12.905] (II) solid
>   [ 12.905] (II) copy
>   [ 12.905] (II) composite (RENDER acceleration)
>   [ 12.905] (II) put_image
>   [ 12.905] (II) get_image

The temp fix is to switch this off and enable SNA Acceleration by creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-conf as described in [How can I enable the SNA acceleration method for Intel cards, under Ubuntu 12.04 - 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225356/how-can-i-enable-the-sna-acceleration-method-for-intel-cards-under-ubuntu-12-04)

Note also there is an open bug for this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1140716